# jQuery Title Change with array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this code to change the page title based on array elements. But there is something wrong with this code. I need the page title show the entire array only when the browser tab is inactive. When the browser tab is active show the real page title. This is the code that I got so far

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hgmvqasn/2/

```js
/*
*
Title Change Plugin, adapted
*
*/

window.onload = function() {
  var pageTitle = document.title;
  var appeal = ["Hello! ♥","Welcome Back!", "Are you sure?"];
  var blinkEvent = null;
   document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e){
     var isPageActive = document.visibilityState;
     console.log(isPageActive);
     if (isPageActive == "hidden") {
       blinkEvent;
     } else {
       document.title = pageTitle;
       clearInterval(blinkEvent); 
     }
   })
  blinkEvent = setInterval(function() {
  function blink(){
      for (i = 0; i < appeal.length; i++){
              document.title = appeal[i];
              console.log(appeal[i]);
        }
        // To make instant page title change (no wait the interval)
      document.title = appeal[1];
    }
  }, 1900);
};
```

The code above does not display all items in the array or displays them in wrong way. In addition the interval is not interrupted when the tab becomes active again.Can someone help me?

Comment: The `for` loop is starting multiple timers, and they all run at about the same time. Each one replaces the title with a different one, and all you see is the change from the last one.

Comment: You just need one interval timer, not one for each array element. The timer should increment `i` (wrapping around when it reaches the end) and show that title.

Comment: Also `blinkEvent` only contains the last timer. So `clearInterval(blinkEvent)` only stops one of the timers, not all of them.

Comment: Thank's @Barmar, I understand. But how to solve this issue?

Comment: `document.hidden` is obsolete. The property you want is `visibilityState`, which can have values `visible` or `hidden`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState. Also see the note there about Safari using the `pagehide` event instead of `visibilitychange`.

Comment: I updated the code, but still not working =(

Comment: What do you expect `blinkEvent;` to do?

Comment: Change the page title with the "appeal" array items one-by-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `for` loop. You just want one timer, not a timer for each string in the `appeal` array. That timer should increment the index and display the next title.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var pageTitle = document.title;
  var appeal = ["Hello! ♥", "Welcome Back!", "Are you sure?"];
  var appeal_index = 0;
  var blinkEvent = null;
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
    var isPageActive = document.visibilityState;
    console.log(isPageActive);
    if (isPageActive == "hidden") {
      start_timer();
    } else {
      document.title = pageTitle;
      clearInterval(blinkEvent);
    }
  })

  function blink() {
    document.title = appeal[appeal_index];
    console.log(appeal[appeal_index]);
    appeal_index++;
    if (appeal_index >= appeal.length) { // wrap around to beginning
      appeal_index = 0;
    }
  }

  function start_timer() {
    blink();
    blinkEvent = setInterval(blink, 1900);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I just replaced the startTimer () variable with start_timer (). Worked perfectly